# How to handle Python Selenium Authentication window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium. Want to do Authentication while opening a URL using selenium in python.

The authentication window screenshot (the window opens as soon as I enter the URL)

[image]

I have tried using the user name and password in the URL but the password has @ in it so replaced that with %40 but still didn't work (still the authentication window is coming)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://' + usrname + ':' + password + '@' + MY_COLLEGE_URL)
# replacing @ in the password with %40 also not working
```

Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: you can type user name and password using selenium. Check the documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms

Comment: The window you see comes from the browser not from the page - it's not an alert so selenium isn't capable of handling it. There are options - but are you sure you're doing the url method right? - when doing it right, `@` doesn't become `%40`  -  Does it work when you manually do it?  - and then try your approach on a test page (for example admin:admin on here: https://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth)

Comment: No @ doesn't become %40. I saw that on some youtube comment, so tried it. Is there any other way to handle browser authentication window using python?